# Joomla - Getting parameter into external file

Tags: php, joomla, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to embed vimeo video playlist script in module but I have problem with getting $token param.

This is file where I get the vimeo key, secret and token using official php library: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

outside-web-root-settings.php:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../..' ));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$session =& JFactory::getSession();

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_module');
$moduleParams = new JRegistry();
$moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
    $vkey = $moduleParams->get('vimkey'); 
    $vsecret = $moduleParams->get('vimsecret'); 
    $vtoken = $moduleParams->get('vimtoken'); 

    $key = '$vkey'; 
    $secret = '$vsecret';
    $token = '$vtoken';
```

The script correctly get `$vkey` and `$vsecret` params but not the `$vtoken`. I get this error on console:

> You must provide a valid authenticated access token.

and I get this for the var_dump of the $vtoken

```
string(32) "3wsrsdf234mytoken2342werwr"
```

But when I change param $token to:

```
$token = '3wsrsdf234mytoken2342werwr';
```

Then script work properly. How can I fix this issue?

---

vimeo_data.php

```
require_once("../../outside-web-root-settings.php");

if(!isset($_REQUEST['type']) || !isset($_REQUEST['page']) || !isset($_REQUEST['per_page']) || IsNullOrEmpty($key) || IsNullOrEmpty($secret) || IsNullOrEmpty($token)) exit("PHP Vimeo information missing!");

function IsNullOrEmpty($v){
    return (!isset($v) || trim($v)==='');
}

$type = $_REQUEST['type'];
$page = $_REQUEST['page'];
$per_page = $_REQUEST['per_page'];
$path = isset($_REQUEST['path']) && !IsNullOrEmpty($_REQUEST['path']) ? $_REQUEST['path'] : null;
$user = isset($_REQUEST['user']) && !IsNullOrEmpty($_REQUEST['user']) ? $_REQUEST['user'] : null;
$query = isset($_REQUEST['query']) && !IsNullOrEmpty($_REQUEST['query']) ? $_REQUEST['query'] : null;
$sort = isset($_REQUEST['sort']) && !IsNullOrEmpty($_REQUEST['sort']) ? $_REQUEST['sort'] : 'date';

require("../autoload.php");
use Vimeo\Vimeo;
$vimeo = new Vimeo($key, $secret, $token);



if($type == 'vimeo.channel'){

    //Get a list of videos in a Channel - https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/channels/{channel_id}/videos
    $result = $vimeo->request("/channels/$path/videos", array(
                                                    'page'=> $page,
                                                    'per_page' => $per_page,
                                                    'fields' => 'uri,name,description,duration,width,height,privacy,pictures.sizes',
                                                    'sort' => $sort,
                                                    'direction' => 'asc',                                   
                                                    'query' => $query));

}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution of my problem. Parameters were not loaded correctly.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../..' ));
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$session = JFactory::getSession();

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT params FROM #__modules WHERE module = 'mod_module'");

$module = $db->loadObject();
$moduleParams = new JRegistry();
$moduleParams->loadString($module->params);

    $key = $moduleParams->get('vimkey'); 
    $secret = $moduleParams->get('vimsecret'); 
    $token = $moduleParams->get('vimtoken');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// What worked for me. Joomla 3.7

    // Init Joomla Framework      

    $joomlaBase = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysitedirectory/'; // specific to my development environment        
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define('JPATH_BASE', $joomlaBase);
    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
    $mainframe->initialise();

    // Get params from Database

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $db->setQuery("SELECT params FROM #__modules WHERE module = 'mod_my_module'");
    $module = $db->loadObject();

    $moduleParams = new JRegistry();
    $moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
    // This param_name value is set in the admin section of the module and defined in the xml manifest file as a field name.
    $key = $moduleParams->get('param_name', 'default value here not mandatory');

    // use $key as you like.
```

This is just my example. Thanks @Frostbourn